# pywinauto: type_keys sends text to wrong text box

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I am trying to input text into the "Start Row" text box using pywinauto

[image]

I am using the folowing code:

```html
import pywinauto
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().connect(title='HD Die Tester')

app['HD Die Tester'].TkChild9.type_keys("hello")
```

however the text appears in the "Start Col (x)" textbox. this is the one i clicked on last.

[image]

i.e. if i want the text to appear in the TkChild9 text field I have to manually click on it for the text to appear there. I tried to do an automated click however that doesn't work.

this is the class tree for the my Gui of interest:

```html
app['HD Die Tester'].PrintControlIdentifiers()

Control Identifiers:

TkTopLevel - 'HD Die Tester'    (L337, T254, R757, B735)
['HD Die TesterTkTopLevel', 'HD Die Tester', 'TkTopLevel']
child_window(title="HD Die Tester", class_name="TkTopLevel")
   | 
   | TkChild - ''    (L345, T305, R749, B727)
   | ['TkChild', 'HD Die TesterTkChild', 'TkChild0', 'TkChild1', 'HD Die TesterTkChild0', 'HD Die TesterTkChild1']
   | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L345, T706, R749, B727)
   |    | ['Static', 'HD Die TesterStatic', 'Static0', 'Static1', 'HD Die TesterStatic0', 'HD Die TesterStatic1']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Static")
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L544, T645, R550, B666)
   |    | ['Static2', 'HD Die TesterStatic2']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Static")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - ''    (L345, T619, R749, B645)
   |    | ['Button', 'HD Die TesterButton', 'Button0', 'Button1', 'HD Die TesterButton0', 'HD Die TesterButton1']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | TkChild - ''    (L345, T687, R749, B706)
   |    | ['TkChild2', 'HD Die TesterTkChild2']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L345, T666, R546, B687)
   |    | ['Static3', 'HD Die TesterStatic3']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Static")
   |    | 
   |    | TkChild - ''    (L418, T599, R749, B618)
   |    | ['TkChild3', 'HD Die TesterTkChild3']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   |    | 
   |    | TkChild - ''    (L418, T578, R749, B597)
   |    | ['TkChild4', 'HD Die TesterTkChild4']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   |    | 
   |    | TkChild - ''    (L418, T557, R749, B576)
   |    | ['TkChild5', 'HD Die TesterTkChild5']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   |    | 
   |    | TkChild - ''    (L418, T536, R749, B555)
   |    | ['TkChild6', 'HD Die TesterTkChild6']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L345, T598, R387, B619)
   |    | ['Static4', 'HD Die TesterStatic4']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Static")
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L345, T577, R383, B598)
   |    | ['Static5', 'HD Die TesterStatic5']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Static")
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L345, T556, R418, B577)
   |    | ['Static6', 'HD Die TesterStatic6']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Static")
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L345, T535, R413, B556)
   |    | ['Static7', 'HD Die TesterStatic7']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Static")
   |    | 
   |    | TkChild - ''    (L345, T523, R749, B525)
   |    | ['TkChild7', 'HD Die TesterTkChild7']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - ''    (L345, T487, R749, B513)
   |    | ['Button2', 'HD Die TesterButton2']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - ''    (L345, T461, R749, B487)
   |    | ['Button3', 'HD Die TesterButton3']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | TkChild - ''    (L418, T441, R749, B460)
   |    | ['TkChild8', 'HD Die TesterTkChild8']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   |    | 
   |    | TkChild - ''    (L418, T420, R749, B439)
   |    | ['TkChild9', 'HD Die TesterTkChild9']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L345, T440, R408, B461)
   |    | ['Static8', 'HD Die TesterStatic8']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Static")
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L345, T419, R401, B440)
   |    | ['Static9', 'HD Die TesterStatic9']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Static")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - ''    (L692, T394, R749, B419)
   |    | ['Button4', 'HD Die TesterButton4']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - ''    (L527, T394, R582, B419)
   |    | ['Button5', 'HD Die TesterButton5']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - ''    (L358, T394, R404, B419)
   |    | ['Button6', 'HD Die TesterButton6']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L345, T305, R749, B326)
   |    | ['Static10', 'HD Die TesterStatic10']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Static")
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L345, T373, R749, B394)
   |    | ['Static11', 'HD Die TesterStatic11']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Static")
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L345, T352, R749, B373)
   |    | ['Static12', 'HD Die TesterStatic12']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Static")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - ''    (L345, T326, R749, B352)
   |    | ['Button7', 'HD Die TesterButton7']
   |    | child_window(class_name="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | TkChild - ''    (L345, T305, R346, B306)
   |    | ['TkChild10', 'HD Die TesterTkChild10']
   |    | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L345, T706, R749, B727)
   | ['Static', 'HD Die TesterStatic', 'Static0', 'Static1', 'HD Die TesterStatic0', 'HD Die TesterStatic1']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L544, T645, R550, B666)
   | ['Static2', 'HD Die TesterStatic2']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Button - ''    (L345, T619, R749, B645)
   | ['Button', 'HD Die TesterButton', 'Button0', 'Button1', 'HD Die TesterButton0', 'HD Die TesterButton1']
   | child_window(class_name="Button")
   | 
   | TkChild - ''    (L345, T687, R749, B706)
   | ['TkChild2', 'HD Die TesterTkChild2']
   | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L345, T666, R546, B687)
   | ['Static3', 'HD Die TesterStatic3']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | TkChild - ''    (L418, T599, R749, B618)
   | ['TkChild3', 'HD Die TesterTkChild3']
   | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   | 
   | TkChild - ''    (L418, T578, R749, B597)
   | ['TkChild4', 'HD Die TesterTkChild4']
   | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   | 
   | TkChild - ''    (L418, T557, R749, B576)
   | ['TkChild5', 'HD Die TesterTkChild5']
   | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   | 
   | TkChild - ''    (L418, T536, R749, B555)
   | ['TkChild6', 'HD Die TesterTkChild6']
   | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L345, T598, R387, B619)
   | ['Static4', 'HD Die TesterStatic4']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L345, T577, R383, B598)
   | ['Static5', 'HD Die TesterStatic5']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L345, T556, R418, B577)
   | ['Static6', 'HD Die TesterStatic6']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L345, T535, R413, B556)
   | ['Static7', 'HD Die TesterStatic7']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | TkChild - ''    (L345, T523, R749, B525)
   | ['TkChild7', 'HD Die TesterTkChild7']
   | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   | 
   | Button - ''    (L345, T487, R749, B513)
   | ['Button2', 'HD Die TesterButton2']
   | child_window(class_name="Button")
   | 
   | Button - ''    (L345, T461, R749, B487)
   | ['Button3', 'HD Die TesterButton3']
   | child_window(class_name="Button")
   | 
   | TkChild - ''    (L418, T441, R749, B460)
   | ['TkChild8', 'HD Die TesterTkChild8']
   | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   | 
   | TkChild - ''    (L418, T420, R749, B439)
   | ['TkChild9', 'HD Die TesterTkChild9']
   | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L345, T440, R408, B461)
   | ['Static8', 'HD Die TesterStatic8']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L345, T419, R401, B440)
   | ['Static9', 'HD Die TesterStatic9']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Button - ''    (L692, T394, R749, B419)
   | ['Button4', 'HD Die TesterButton4']
   | child_window(class_name="Button")
   | 
   | Button - ''    (L527, T394, R582, B419)
   | ['Button5', 'HD Die TesterButton5']
   | child_window(class_name="Button")
   | 
   | Button - ''    (L358, T394, R404, B419)
   | ['Button6', 'HD Die TesterButton6']
   | child_window(class_name="Button")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L345, T305, R749, B326)
   | ['Static10', 'HD Die TesterStatic10']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L345, T373, R749, B394)
   | ['Static11', 'HD Die TesterStatic11']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L345, T352, R749, B373)
   | ['Static12', 'HD Die TesterStatic12']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Button - ''    (L345, T326, R749, B352)
   | ['Button7', 'HD Die TesterButton7']
   | child_window(class_name="Button")
   | 
   | TkChild - ''    (L345, T305, R346, B306)
   | ['TkChild10', 'HD Die TesterTkChild10']
   | child_window(class_name="TkChild")
```

please advise.

the following are my debugging efforts:

**1. programitically find the textbox area:**

```html
import pywinauto
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().connect(title='HD Die Tester')
app['HD Die Tester']['TkChild9'].draw_outline(colour='green', thickness=2)
```

this is what I see.

[image]

**2. using set_text to input characters into the textbox**

```html
app['HD Die Tester']['TkChild9'].set_text("hello")
```

error message occurred

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    app['HD Die Tester']['TkChild9'].set_text("hello")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 182, in __call__
    format(self.criteria[-1]['best_match']))
AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'set_text' were found (typo?)
```

**3. Using set_keyboard_focus**

```html
app['HD Die Tester']['TkChild9'].set_keyboard_focus().type_keys("hello", set_foreground=False)
```

this is the output:

```html
<hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper - '', TkChild, 2427666>
hello
```

nothing comes up on the Gui

[image]

Comment: Best match algorithm can have some confusing cases like this. Use method `.draw_outline()` to check which element is really matched to `TkChild9`.

Comment: i did, TkChild9 points to the right text field.

Comment: Well, how about `.set_text("hello")`? If it does the trick, maybe it's worth trying `.set_keyboard_focus().type_keys("hello", set_foreground=False)`.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I have updated my Question with the recommendations you made, please review.

Comment: Well, maybe `.click_input()` method will help to set input focus correctly before typing. Also `.wrapper_object()` obviously returns `HwndWrapper` instead of `EditWrapper` so it means the element is not detected as Edit box. It can be explicitly converted to `EditWrapper` object. Use this import: `from pywinauto.controls.win32_controls import EditWrapper`.

Comment: And then `edit = EditWrapper(app['HD Die Tester']['TkChild9'].wrapper_object()); edit.set_edit_text("hello")` or try `type_keys(...)`.

Comment: the .click_input() and then type_keys(...) works,

Answer (score 0):

`.click_input()` method will help to set input focus correctly before typing. Also `.wrapper_object()` obviously returns `HwndWrapper` instead of `EditWrapper` so it means the element is not detected as Edit box. It can be explicitly converted to `EditWrapper` object. Use this import for that purpose:

```
from pywinauto.controls.win32_controls import EditWrapper

edit = EditWrapper(app['HD Die Tester']['TkChild9'].wrapper_object())
edit.set_edit_text("hello") # or try type_keys(...)
```